# Populating listbox based on other combobox selections?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I've run into a road block while trying to create a music inventory system. So I have two comboboxes (cb1 and cb2) and a listbox (lb). A user selects from cb1 whether to search for a music album be either genre or artist. Then cb2 populates with either a list of artists or a list of genres depending on the cb1 selection with data from a SQL database that I created in the VS table designer. Then finally, lb populates with data based on the selection in cb2, so for example if cb2 says "Pop" then lb populates with albums under the "Pop" genre. I have cb1 and cb2 down, but I can't seem to populate lb with the combination of that data. I did cb2 manually since there's only "genre" and "artist" but I have 7 genres and 37 artists so it would be way too much redundant code to do manually.

So far, I have a classes that convert GenreToAlbums and ArtistToAlbums:

```
    public List<string> GenreToAlbums(String genre)
    {
        List<string> albums = new List<string>();
        String s = "select name from Albums where genre = '" + genre + "'";

        SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=ALYSSAUSF\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=UserData;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s, c);
        c.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read()) 
        {
            albums.Add((string)reader["name"]);
        }

        return albums;
    }

    public List<string> ArtistToAlbums(String artist)
    {
        List<string> albums = new List<string>();
        String s = "select name from Albums where artist = '" + artist + "'";

        SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=ALYSSAUSF\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=UserData;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s, c);
        c.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            albums.Add((string)reader["name"]);
        }

        return albums;
    }
```

And then this is the cb2 event handler to populate lb:

```
    private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ClassItems.selectedItem == "Genre")
        {
            String selectedGenre = comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();

            List<string> albums = GenreToAlbums(selectedGenre);
            listBox1.DataSource = albums;
            listBox1.DisplayMember = "name";
        }
        else if (ClassItems.selectedItem == "Artist")
        {
            String selectedArtist = comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();

            List<string> albums = ArtistToAlbums(selectedArtist);
            listBox1.DataSource = albums;
            listBox1.DisplayMember = "name";
        }
    }
```

I have a public class `ClassItems` that handles a global variable, SelectedItem, whose value is changed to either "Genre" or "Artist" in the event handler class for cb1. Where is the issue in my code?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is not working?

Comment: Take 15 mins to learn how to properly create queries using parameterized statements and SQL parameters. Your SelectedIndex cant know if the user is going to also pick from the other or what order they will pick them in.  You need a button so they can tell you - 'I am done with filters, this is what I want'

Comment: @DanWilson populating the listbox lb isn't working with whatever code I have

Comment: @Plutonix The second combobox doesn't get enabled until a user selects from the first combobox so I do have that control

Comment: Well, the standard remedy for "it doesnt work" is to [debug your code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx) and read [ask] and take the [tour] to give more useful problem descriptions

Comment: Put a breakpoint in `comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged()` and step through the code, checking each statement's result against what you expect.

Comment: `"select name from Albums where artist = '" + artist + "'";` If you actually have a text column for the artist (or genre) you'll want to also research DB Design.  Anytime you have repeating data like `Beatles`, `Beatles`,`Beatles`,`Beatles`,`Beatles`  you missed a relationship

Answer (score 0):

After staring at it for a couple hours I realized my error was in casting the selected item in cb2 to a string. It showed up as a DataView error and so I changed that to use `GetItemText();`